# UnboundLocalError raised before local variable assignment in function local scope

Tags: python, function, scope

In this example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def foo():
    l.append(10)

foo()
```

`UnboundLocalError` exception is not raised because there is no assignment to the variable inside the function `foo()`.
This code results in error as expected:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def foo():
    l.append(10)
    print(l)
    l += [10]

foo()
```

But I am getting error at line `l.append(10)` i.e. the first time I reference the list. I was expecting exception to be raised at `l += [10]`, when the assignment occurs.

Does this mean that `l` gets evaluated once the function is defined just like the default arguments?

Comment: Yes, completely, thank you for the link

Comment: "But I am getting error at line l.append(10) i.e. the first time I reference the list. I was expecting exception to be raised at l += [10], when the assignment occurs." Why? The error isn't for *assigning*, it's for *referencing* an unbound local variable. The error message should state "local variable 'l' **referenced** before assignment"

Comment: "Does this mean that l gets evaluated once the function is defined just like the default arguments?" No, that isn't what it means at all. `l` gets evaluated each time the function is called.

Comment: "The error message should state "local variable 'l' referenced before assignment" " Yes it is, I should have explicitly write it in the question.
"No, that isn't what it means at all. `l` gets evaluated each time the function is called" - This is not answered in the selected question. Now nothing is missing.